# How to loop through Array of objects from specific index

Tags: javascript

I have a `test array` and a `test object`. I want to compare each element of `test array` with `test object`, but only those elements which are after the `test object` in the `test array`.

I have done it via the following example. Do we have any elegant way to do the same.

```js
let testArray = [{ id: xx, name: 'C' },
    { id: xy, name: 'B' },
    { id: yz, name: 'C' },
    { id: ab, name: 'D' },
    { id: bc, name: 'E' },
    { id: cd, name: 'C' },
    { id: ce, name: 'E' },
    { id: ef, name: 'C' }];

let testObj = { id: 3, name: 'C' };

for (let i = testArray.indexOf(testObj) + 1; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  if (testObj.name === testArray[i].name) {
    console.log(testArray[i].id); // expected - object with id : cd and ef
    // if I change test object to { id: cd, name: 'C' } then answer should be object with id : ef
  }
}
```

Comment: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your expected result. Why does `{ id: 3, name: 'C' }` return objects with `id: 6` and `id: 7`, but `{ id: 6, name: 'C' }` returns `id: 7`?

Comment: ^ If you're looking for "objects with the same name, with IDs higher than the given ID", the results should be `id: 6` and `id: 8`. For `{ id: 6, name: 'C' }`, i'd expect the result to be `id: 8`. But also - what happens if the suggested object isn't found? Is the passed-in object only compared on name, or ID too?

Comment: I am looking for an object with a same name but after the place of that object in the array. this is not about id at all.

Comment: @kandarp The confusion was that prior to your edit, you had used `id: 7` as a return value instead of `id: 8`. The latest edit seems to correct that, but the IDs no longer match the object you're trying to find (nor are they valid javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
testArray.filter(i => i.id > testObj.id).forEach(i => console.log(i))
```

Just one line for filter and show all itens filtered.

Comment: that's a nice one

Comment: You're assuming the array is sorted by ids in ascending order.

Comment: The array can sort any way (asc or desc). It will work.

Comment: @mbojko, I could be wrong but I think regardless of order, the filter function will remove the IDs less than or equal to the testObj.id.

Comment: OP says that for `id: 3`, the result should be objects with `id: 6` and `id: 7`. The result of this code would also log objects `id: 4`, `id: 5`, and `id: 8`. OP also seems to be doing an equality check on the `name` property. I believe the question isn't clear on its expectations, and therefore isn't in an answerable state.

Comment: @TylerRoper, yeah I'm honestly a little unclear on what OP is looking for but you could add `&& i.name === testObj.name` to the filter and only get "matches" after the testObj.

Comment: I think you all miss-understood with id, I don't want to compare id of the object. I wanted to ask about the index of that object in the array.

Comment: It is, even heading itself clarify the requirement.  Can you please closely look to for loop that I used. I wanted to have all the element of same name from the array, which are coming after test-object.

Answer (score 0):

The following soluce will look for the index where the `id` is encountered, and then loop on the target array from the position.

Elegant way is highly subjective thought. We will all give you **alternative** syntax. Apply the one that is the most suitiable to your needs and that match your general coding style.

```js
const testArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'C',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'D',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'E',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'C',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'E',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'C',
  },
];

const testObj = {
  id: 3,
  name: 'C',
};

// Find where to start
const pos = testArray.findIndex(x => x.id === testObj.id);

// Cut the array where you want to start looking and loop on it
testArray.slice(pos).forEach(({
  id,
  name,
}) => {
  if (name === testObj.name) {
    console.log(id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the correct object in the array.

Capture only items after that object by using [`slice(index+1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Finally, [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get objects with matching `name` values.

```js
let testArray = [{ id: 1, name: 'C' },{ id: 2, name: 'B' },{ id: 3, name: 'C' },{ id: 4, name: 'D' },{ id: 5, name: 'E' },{ id: 6, name: 'C' },{ id: 7, name: 'E' },{ id: 8, name: 'C' }];
let testObj = { id: 3, name: 'C' };

const getItemsAfterObj = (arr, obj) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id && o.name === obj.name);
  if (idx === -1) throw "Object not found in array.";
  return arr.slice(idx+1).filter(o => o.name === obj.name);
};

const items = getItemsAfterObj(testArray,testObj);
console.log(items);
```